# how to create call accept and reject buttons similar to default buttons in android

Tags: android, layout

I want to create call accept and reject buttons looks similar to default buttons and having functionality same
pls. answer it

Answer (score 0):

Well not exactly but try browsing this directory, it contains some images that android uses:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/24ccf3c59077d81b0dd3b314822ff7dab215c165

Hope it might help a bit.